# Switching between pages using customtkinter

Tags: python, class, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

I try to swicth between pages but I could not make that happen. What should I do?

main_page

```
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk
from habit_add_remove_page import *
from habit_change_page import *
from habit_metrics import *

class HabitTrackerApp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = ctk.CTk()
        self.window.geometry("1000x600")
        self.window._set_appearance_mode("dark")

        self.create_frames()
        self.create_labels()
        self.create_buttons()

    def create_frames(self):
        self.frame_1 = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self.window, width=900, height=400, fg_color="white", bg_color="grey")
        self.frame_1.grid(padx=50, pady=5, sticky="n")

        self.frame_2 = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self.window, width=400, height=50, fg_color="white", bg_color="grey")
        self.frame_2.grid(pady=5)

        self.frame_3 = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self.window, width=400, height=50, fg_color="white", bg_color="grey")
        self.frame_3.grid()

    def create_labels(self):
        number = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.frame_1, text="Nr", text_color="Black")
        number.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=2, sticky="WENS")

        habit = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.frame_1, text="Habit", text_color="Black")
        habit.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=30, pady=2, sticky="WENS")

        description = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.frame_1, text="Decription", text_color="Black")
        description.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=120, pady=2, sticky="WENS")

        last_done = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.frame_1, text="Last Done", text_color="Black")
        last_done.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=70, pady=2, sticky="WENS")

        current_streak = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.frame_1, text="Current Streak", text_color="Black")
        current_streak.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=50, pady=2, sticky="WENS")

        progress = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.frame_1, text="Progress", text_color="Black")
        progress.grid(row=0, column=5, padx=30, pady=2, sticky="WENS")

    def create_buttons(self):
        button_edit = ctk.CTkButton(master=self.frame_2, width=180, height=50, text="Edit", text_color="White", fg_color="grey", command=self.button_edit_func)
        button_edit.pack(side="left")

        button_mark_done = ctk.CTkButton(master=self.frame_2, width=180, height=50, text="Mark Done", text_color="White", fg_color="grey", command=self.button_mark_done_func)
        button_mark_done.pack(side="right")

        button_add_habit = ctk.CTkButton(master=self.frame_3, width=180, height=50, text="Add Habit", text_color="White", fg_color="grey", command=self.button_add_habit_func)
        button_add_habit.pack(side="left")

        button_metrics = ctk.CTkButton(master=self.frame_3, width=180, height=50, text="Metrics", text_color="White", fg_color="grey", command=self.button_metrics_func)
        button_metrics.pack(side="right")

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        frame_name = frame_class.__name__
        frame_name = tk.tkraise()

    def button_edit_func(self):
        self.switch_frame(HabitChange)

    def button_mark_done_func(self):
        return "mark_done"

    def button_metrics_func(self):
        return "metric"

    def button_add_habit_func(self):
        return "add_habit"

    def run(self):
        self.window.mainloop()

app = HabitTrackerApp()
app.run()
```

metrics_page

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ctk

class MetricsApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,window):
        super().__init__(window)
        self.metric = ctk.CTk()
        self.metric.geometry("1000x600")
        self.metric._set_appearance_mode("dark")
        
        self.create_widgets()
    
    def create_widgets(self):
        habit_labels = []
        habit_texts = ["Habit name: ", "Habit name: ", "Habit name: ", "Habit name: ", "Habit name: ", "Habit name: ", "Habit name: "]
        
        for text in habit_texts:
            label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self, width=800, height=60, corner_radius=4, text_color="black", fg_color="grey", bg_color="grey", text=text, anchor="w")
            label.grid(padx=100, pady=4)
            habit_labels.append(label)
        
        button = ctk.CTkButton(master=self, height=60, width=200, fg_color="dark grey", bg_color="dark grey", text_color="white", text="Back to Menu")
        button.grid(padx=0, pady=50)
        
        # TODO: Button command
    
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MetricsApp()
    app.mainloop()`
```

edit_page

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ctk

class HabitChange(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.habit_change = ctk.CTk()
        self.habit_change._set_appearance_mode("dark")
        self.habit_change.geometry("1000x600")
        self.habit_change.title("Habit Tracker")
        self.habit_change.resizable(height=False, width=False)

        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        habit_name_label_1 = ctk.CTkLabel(self,
                                      text="Change Habit Name",
                                      width=1000,
                                      height=25,
                                      fg_color=("grey")
                                      )
        habit_name_label_1.grid(padx=0, pady=2)

        habit_name_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(self,
                                    width=1000,
                                    height=75,
                                    fg_color=("white"),
                                    )
        habit_name_entry.grid()

        habit_description_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self,
                                            text="Habit Description",
                                            width=1000,
                                            height=25,
                                            fg_color=("grey"))
        habit_description_label.grid(padx=0, pady=2, sticky="W")

        habit_description_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(self,
                                            width=1000,
                                            height=75,
                                            fg_color=("white"))
        habit_description_entry.grid()

        habit_goal_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self,
                                    text="Goal",
                                    width=1000,
                                    height=25,
                                    fg_color=("grey"))
        habit_goal_label.grid(padx=0, pady=2)

        habit_goal_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(self,
                                    width=1000,
                                    height=75,
                                    fg_color=("white"))
        habit_goal_entry.grid()

        def entries_get():
            habitname = habit_name_entry.get()
            habitdescription = habit_description_entry.get()
            habitgoal = habit_goal_entry.get()
            print(habitname, habitdescription, habitgoal)

        def optionmenu_callback(choice):
            print("optionmenu dropdown clicked:", choice)

        combobox = ctk.CTkOptionMenu(master=self,
                                values=["day", "month", "year"],
                                width=1000,
                                height=25,
                                command=optionmenu_callback)
        combobox.grid(padx=0, pady=30)
        combobox.set("Select Habits Periodicity")  # set initial value

        frame_1 = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self)
        frame_1.grid()
        button_1 = ctk.CTkButton(master=frame_1,
                            width=200,
                            height=75,
                            text="Save Changes",
                            command=entries_get,
                            bg_color="green",
                            fg_color="green")
        button_1.pack(side="left")
        button_2 = ctk.CTkButton(master=frame_1,
                            width=200,
                            height=75,
                            text="Cancel",
                            command=entries_get,
                            bg_color="blue",
                            fg_color="blue")
        button_2.pack(side="right")

        frame_2 = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self)
        frame_2.grid()
        button_3 = ctk.CTkButton(master=frame_2,
                            width=400,
                            height=75,
                            text="Delete Habit",
                            command=entries_get,
                            bg_color="red",
                            fg_color="red")
        button_3.pack(side="bottom")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = HabitChange()
    app.mainloop()`
```

add_remove_page

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ctk

class HabitAddRemove(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._set_appearance_mode("dark")
        self.geometry("1000x600")
        self.title("Habit Tracker")
        self.resizable(height=False, width=False)

        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        habit_name_label_1 = ctk.CTkLabel(self,
                                      text="Change Habit Name",
                                      width=1000,
                                      height=25,
                                      fg_color=("grey")
                                      )
        habit_name_label_1.grid(padx=0, pady=2)

        habit_name_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(self,
                                    width=1000,
                                    height=75,
                                    fg_color=("white"),
                                    )
        habit_name_entry.grid()

        habit_description_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self,
                                            text="Habit Description",
                                            width=1000,
                                            height=25,
                                            fg_color=("grey"))
        habit_description_label.grid(padx=0, pady=2, sticky="W")

        habit_description_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(self,
                                            width=1000,
                                            height=75,
                                            fg_color=("white"))
        habit_description_entry.grid()

        habit_goal_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self,
                                    text="Goal",
                                    width=1000,
                                    height=25,
                                    fg_color=("grey"))
        habit_goal_label.grid(padx=0, pady=2)

        habit_goal_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(self,
                                    width=1000,
                                    height=75,
                                    fg_color=("white"))
        habit_goal_entry.grid()

        def entries_get():
            habitname = habit_name_entry.get()
            habitdescription = habit_description_entry.get()
            habitgoal = habit_goal_entry.get()
            print(habitname, habitdescription, habitgoal)

        def optionmenu_callback(choice):
            print("optionmenu dropdown clicked:", choice)

        combobox = ctk.CTkOptionMenu(master=self,
                                values=["day", "month", "year"],
                                width=1000,
                                height=25,
                                command=optionmenu_callback)
        combobox.grid(padx=0, pady=30)
        combobox.set("Select Habits Periodicity")  # set initial value

        frame_1 = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self)
        frame_1.grid()
        button_1 = ctk.CTkButton(master=frame_1,
                            width=200,
                            height=75,
                            text="Save",
                            command=entries_get,
                            bg_color="green",
                            fg_color="green")
        button_1.pack(side="left")
        button_2 = ctk.CTkButton(master=frame_1,
                            width=200,
                            height=75,
                            text="Cancel",
                            command=entries_get,
                            bg_color="blue",
                            fg_color="blue")
        button_2.pack(side="right")

        frame_2 = ctk.CTkFrame(master=self)
        frame_2.grid()
        button_3 = ctk.CTkButton(master=frame_2,
                            width=400,
                            height=75,
                            text="Delete Habit",
                            command=entries_get,
                            bg_color="red",
                            fg_color="red")
        button_3.pack(side="bottom")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = HabitAddRemove()
    app.mainloop()`
```

I try to do `tkraise()` between pages but I kept getting error such as

```
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'tkraise'
```